# Interview appointment during work time

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-offer, ethics, internship

I'm finishing my 6 months internship at a software company. I'm pretty sure soon I'll receive an offer here.
Meanwhile I sent my CV to a company I'd really like to work with. They showed interest and suggested to meet in one of the next mornings. 
During the day I'm busy with my internship and in these day I'm working on a project they assigned totally to me.

**First question**: Is it a good idea to take 2 hours break from my internship and do this interview, or should I propose a different time?
(It would not be a problem for me to take 2 hours break).

**Second question**: I really like this new company and I don't want to miss this opportunity. But at the same - in case I'll receive an offer by this new company - I want to make them understand that I have to wait the end of the internship and see what the company where I'm now has to offer. How can I do this in a professional way?

Answer (score 14):

1. Just take the two hour break and inform your current employer that you have an errand to do.
2. Inform the potential employer during the interview the earliest start date

Comment: One should note that most jobs have at least one month's notice and a new employee takes a few months to get up to  speed. If you are the right person the company will wait an extra 8 weeks or so

Answer (score 5):

Your questions nearly answer themselves already.

1° You ask if you should take a 2-hour break, and mention at the same time that this would not be a problem. Just do as you said. If the question *"Shouldn't you be at your current work ?"* (happened once to me) arises, just say they trust you with schedule since you always deliver.

2° Simply state you cannot, for legal(EDIT : I mean contractual) reasons, accept an offer before XX.XX.2017, and there is no way to work around this constraint. If this fits the employers' need, he will be fine. If his timeline can't agree with yours, he will just thank you for your time.

Comment: "*for legal reasons* Lying during an interview is not a great idea, especially when it's a bad lie. No one's going to buy this and most people will reasonably conclude that you're waiting to hear from another potential employer. And they're now wondering why you felt the need to lie about it.

Comment: @Lilienthal In your opinion what should I say instead?

Comment: @Dygne Depends on the timing and your profile. If you're a student or recent graduate then most employers hiring from that group know that people have multiple offers and that choices are typically made during the latter half of the school year or shortly after graduation. It doesn't really matter how you word it as long as you're clear in your communication and don't give deadlines you can't keep.

Comment: " ...for legal reasons..." NO!. Even if they don't call you on your BS, then they're going to wonder...what legal reasons? Is that the day this guy gets off parole for murder? or what? The best approach should you receive and offer is to make clear that you've commited to your internship until such and such date. This is true and demonstrates that you take commitments to your employer seriously.

Comment: Isn't a contractual 2-week or 1-month notice a legal reason ? I'm not english native, so I might mistake Contractual and Legal.

Answer (score 2):

1. For your first question, no. If you have paid time off at this internship, use half of the day to do the interview.  That way, it is totally above board and should you have a longer interview, you are in the clear.  If you do not, ask for a longer lunch to take care of some personal business.  By all means, don't lie...to your current employer or your (potential) new one.
2. I will repeat the answer of many here and suggest that you should inform them that you aren't available until (date your internship ends).  It seems as though you wish to complete that commitment and that's something you can tell them that's (a) true and (b) puts you in a positive light.

A competing offer from your current employer is not the new employer's business until you actually receive that offer.